# Weak Law of Large Numbers application

Tags: statistics

$f(x)$ is defined as

$$\begin{cases}\frac{2}{x^2} &\text{if } x\geqslant 2 ,& \\ 0 & \text{otherwise } .\end{cases}$$

$X_1, ... , X_n$ is a random sample from that distribution, and I'm trying to determine if the Weak Law of Large Numbers applies.

Do I have to compute the mean and the variance? I've always seen definitions of this law, but never any actual examples.

Comment: what is the expected value (=mean) of this random variable?

Comment: @user66081 I'm not exactly sure.. If I take $X_1, ... $X_n$ and divide it by n, would that be the mean?

Comment: Why are you interested into "checking" the Weak Law of Large Numbers on that particular pdf ? It is a Pareto distribution and has in fact an interesting mode of generation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution#Random_sample_generation), here $2/U$ with $U$ is uniformly distributed on [0,1]). $\frac{2/U_1+2/U_2+\cdots+2/U_n}{n}$ is twice the inverse of the harmonic mean of the $U_k$...